# React: How to add state changing event listeners in hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a little music component that I found online. Currently now it works fine, but I have tried to make en event listener that toggles a state variable whenever the audio component is playing or no.

Currently I toggle this variable manually, whenever the user clicks a button. But if the user is toggling using play/pause buttons on the keyboard, the state variable for "isPlaying" doesn't change unless I toggle it on the `onplay` and `onpause` event listeners.

Unfortunately, this breaks the entire functionality for the hook, and I am nor sure what to do in order to solve it..

Codesandbox here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/freaking-music-player-ldxde?file=/src/hooks/useMusicPlayer.js

This is the part that breaks it: [src/hooks/useMusicPlayer.js - line: 7]

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (state.audioPlayer) {
      //  => Applying these event listeners **** up everything!
      // console.log(state.audioPlayer);
      //   state.audioPlayer.onplay = (event) => {
      //     setState((state) => ({ ...state, isPlaying: true }));
      //   };
      //   state.audioPlayer.onpause = (event) => {
      //     setState((state) => ({ ...state, isPlaying: false }));
      //   };
      state.audioPlayer.onended = event => {
        playNextTrack();
      };
    }
  }, [state, playNextTrack]);
```

The `onended` event works fine.. No trouble whatsoever.. But the other ones are messing up the experience.

## UPDATE: Moving `setState` out of `useEffect`

Adding this method:

```js
  function togglePause() {
    setState((state) => ({
      ...state,
      isPlaying: state.audioPlayer ? !state.audioPlayer.paused : false,
    }));
  }
```

And updating the `useEffect`

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if (state.audioPlayer) {
      console.log(state.audioPlayer);
      state.audioPlayer.onplay = (event: Event) => {
        togglePause();
      };
      state.audioPlayer.onpause = (event: Event) => {
        togglePause();
      };
      state.audioPlayer.onended = (event: Event) => {
        playNextTrack();
      };
    }
  }, [state, playNextTrack]);
```

This however still causes issues..

**Clarification on the actual issue itself**

Once the first `state.audioPlayer` has `ended`, the event listeners aren't transferred to the next Audio Component, whereas by **NOT** having the `onplay` and `onpause` listeners written in `useEffect`, the `onended` is indeed created anew and it works..

Comment: Do not mix React hooks (`useEffect()`) with traditional state management (`setState()`). Use `useState()` instead.

Comment: I see... I have tested this a lot, and useEffect is the only way for me to have the `onended` event listener triggered for the `Audio component` stored in state. How do I move this listener from `useEffect` then?

Comment: I can create a "toggle pause" method, that looks at the `state.audioPlayer.paused` property in order to toggle the `isPlaying` variable whenever triggered, and then use that method to toggle state. Check updated question

Answer (score 1):

There wasn't an actual issue with the code itself. It boils down to the various event handlers. The `onpause` event is implicitly triggered by the `onended` which caused multiple state changes to happen in the same event.

The [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/freaking-music-player-ldxde?file=/src/hooks/useMusicPlayer.js) is now fully working.